# just basic bonehead js not working

Tags: javascript, onload

I'm just a js cut&paster, and can't figure out why this basic `onload foo()` isn't working:

http://jsfiddle.net/birchy/qZqLa/4/

```
<body style=" onload="getClassListAjax()">
    <div id="fred" >some text</div>
</body>

function getClassListAjax() {
alert('here');
document.getElementById("fred").innerHTML = 'some other text';
}
```

Comment: your style attribute looks unclosed ? close the double quotes under body tag

Comment: Also, you may need to switch when your js is loaded from "onload" to either "no wrap - in <head>" or "no wrap - in <body>". Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qZqLa/14/

Comment: The problem seems to be from a function that procedes the one referenced in the onload. If I add it to the fixed jsfiddle code, it breaks there, as well. Can anyone see why this function messes up the one below it?

`    function $_GET(q,s) {
    s = s ? s : window.location.search;
    var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i');
    return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined;
 }
`
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/birchy/qZqLa/17/

Comment: @birchy `/^?/` is an invalid regex expression, and that's why it's breaking the rest of your code. What was your intent with that expression?

Comment: This is stolen code. It is supposed to provide a GET var to js.

Comment: I found different code to provide GET vars to js, and then I realized I don't need it, I can just insert inline PHP to echo the values, so I'm closing this one out. Thanks to all who answered, you helped me through an important logjam...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- Your style attribute is unclosed
- In the left bar of jsfiddle, the onLoad option is selected, which is overriding your `onload` handler. If you fix the style attribute and select "No wrap in `<head>`" or "No wrap in `<body>`", it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/qZqLa/22/

However, I would recommend striving toward [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript):

http://jsfiddle.net/qZqLa/23/

```
<body style="">
    <div id="fred" >some text</div>
</body>

function getClassListAjax() {
    alert('here');
    document.getElementById("fred").innerHTML = 'some other text';
}

window.onload = getClassListAjax;
```